# How to prevent Chrome from terminating on closing of the last opened tab?

Tags: google-chrome

How can I prevent Chrome from terminating on closing the last opened tab? Instead of terminating, I want Chrome to always display a blank open tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On OS X ,  enable 'Warn Before Quitting' - https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95631 .

On other platforms: 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simplelasttab/ganniadnoflaogjededkdpicdfkloajf

[How to enable confirmation alert before closing chrome tabs?](https://superuser.com/questions/704779/how-to-enable-confirmation-alert-before-closing-chrome-tabs)

Answer (score 8):

Popular Chrome extension to prevent browser from closing when last tab closes.

- 4 out of 5 stars rating
- More than 10,000 users

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dont-close-window-with-la/dlnpfhfhmkiebpnlllpehlmklgdggbhn?hl=en

```
Truly disappointing Google hasn't added a settings option for this, 
even after four years of complaints.
```

Comment: Maybe it's easier to understand if you consider that there was a time before tabs... and when close meant close...

Comment: Browser tabs have existed since 1994. The Chromium project started in 2008 and always had tabs. Chrome is based on Chromium. Closing the window means to close the app. Closing the last tab just means to clear its content. At least 10,000 Chrome user have the same expectation. The number is far greater if you add up the users of all the other extensions that fix the last tab problem.

Answer (score 0):

No need to add extension or anything on Chrome instead you could disable home page button which would automatically disable closing Chrome when the last tab is closed.

Comment: How do I disable it?

Comment: it didn't help me, but when I was implying your soulution, I clicked Settings > Appearance > Show Home button V > New tabe page (there was another option - enter custom web address, but I do not want to open some site at the end of my browsing so I left it blank). So, this method did not help me because closing the last tab still closes the whole browser. Google Chrome settings have always been to pathetic. Firefox has many more settings, and you can control everythoing, not like on Google which seems to be a silly kid toy.

Answer (score -2):

I found this solution by chance.

Open a new tab then right click on it and select "pin"

Hopefully it works for you guys.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1082473)

Comment: and if you close even that last pinned tab, the whole browser still closes :-)

Comment: doesn't work because your browser closes after you close the pinned tab.

Comment: I found this to be a useful workaround since I am in a situation where I can't install chrome extensions