# How to prevent accidentally closing Chrome while developing?

Tags: google-chrome

So, I am am developing a [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions) which means I am **constantly accidentally closing Chrome**:

> [image]

And while you may not see it now, I've closed Chrome at least **8 times** because of accidentally moving too fast and clicking the [image] instead of the button for my extension. I mean the top of the button *really is* only **11 pixels** away:

> [image]

Now that you believe I'm not a psycho let me go through what I've tried.

- Setting for it? Nope.
- Another SU Question? **[YES!](https://superuser.com/questions/704779/how-to-enable-confirmation-alert-before-closing-chrome-tabs)** But wait, in the answer of the question it acknowledges that you *can't* stop Chrome from closing without warning when pressing the [image]. Which is exactly my problem. (Yes, I know I can Ctrl + Shift + Tab to bring it back but *really*?)

> [image]

- **[NoClose](https://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/#NoClose)** (also from the same question above) does not work either.
- I didn't even try [the 2 Star Chrome Extension that claims it doesn't work anymore in the description of the extension itself](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-close-protector/lnpifgapnmpninomacbhdlconlpikdai), but I glanced at it for good measure.

How can I disable the [image], show a confirmation, or *anything* like that?

---

Side note 1: **Bob made a good point in chat** about how I could just move the icon to the left in front of the other extension icons. Yeah, that would work. But it's more of a workaround, and I'd still like an answer. Other devs might not have a bunch of extensions installed or have a good reason to be developing without other extensions that could cause conflict. In that case, there would be nothing to move behind of it.

Side note 2: Sort of unrelated but I've also closed Chrome when clicking  [image] in the past, so this question could help even non developers who are as sloppy as me.

Comment: also what you call a workaround but since it never comes to your Problem Probably still the Best Thing for you - On MacOS the Close/Max/Min Buttons of the Window are on the left Side so there you don't have this Problem. I know there are also some kind of Windowlayouts for Linux which have those Bottons on the left Side

Comment: @konqui Thats pretty silly. To suggest using a whole new OS. But yes I use MacOS in addition to Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start typing in this answer box? ;)

[image]

Just thinking outside (actually, inside) the box.

Or, if you wanted to do it with the focus on another tab, you could always open the console (<kbd>F12</kbd>) and paste something along the lines of:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    if (e) {
        e.returnValue = 'Are you sure?';
    }
};
```

Comment: You're a genius, and for making a GIF you have my respect. I'll admit, I hate these kind of workarounds, but you might just be accepted in a week when no one else comes up with anything :P

Comment: @Insane I'm certain there should be a better way to do it, but just the first thing that came to mind!

Comment: @Insane Added a little bit of JS you could add to another tab if you wanted to have a different tab in the foreground. Still haven't stumbled upon a more global option though.

Comment: @Jonno You could just make that bit of JS into a bookmarklet, and BAM! Solved!